# Install g++ ubuntu 14.04 Depends: g++-4.8 (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: 14.04, apt, g++

I just typed:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

and got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++ : Depends: g++-4.8 (>= 4.8.2-5~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried also as per suggestions in other forums:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

None solved my problem. Please help if you know the answer.

EDIT:

As per the suggestion placed in the comment, I tried:

```
sudo apt-cache policy g++-4.8
```

and got the following output:

```
g++-4.8:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.8.2-19ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

By trying:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-4.8
```

I got:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 g++-4.8 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
           Depends: gcc-4.8 (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
           Depends: libstdc++-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What are the output/errors of those `apt-get` commands?

Comment: apt-get update just updates the repository... lots of output lines but no errors...

apt-get -f install gives: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy g++-4.8`

Comment: Try to force the installation via `sudo apt-get install g++-4.8` and add the output into your question. You should see another error message. And we need this message to find the real problem.

Comment: And give me a comment with `@A.B.` Without that I don't get a notification that you have changed your question.

Comment: @A.B. done with edit.

Comment: `apt-cache policy gcc-4.8-base  gcc-4.8 libstdc++-4.8-dev; sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base  gcc-4.8 libstdc++-4.8-dev`

Comment: @A.B. the apt-get command gives an error:
     The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: and `apt-cache policy gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8 libstdc++-4.8-dev`

Comment: @A.B. when I run apt-get install libstdc++-4.8-dev I get: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgcc-4.8-dev (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Come on `apt-cache policy ` but anyway, I have the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is:

```
libstdc++-4.8-dev : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
```

Why? That's why:

- `libstdc++-4.8-dev` in the main repositories depends on `libstdc++-4.8-dev=4.8.2-19ubuntu1`
- `libstdc++-4.8-dev` in the updates repository depends on `libstdc++-4.8-dev=4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04`, which is installed in your system

---

The solution?

*My first choice is, enable the update repository again:*

- Open <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd> and the tab <kbd>Updates</kbd>
- Select `trusty-updates` and `trusty-security` and click <kbd>Close</kbd>

  <sub>If someone has a version for the terminal, then please let me know.</sub>

  [image]
- <kbd>Reload</kbd>

  [image]
- Install

  ```
  sudo apt-get install g++
  ```

---

*My second choice, downgrade*

Hmm, I would say, that's a bad idea **=)**

Comment: enabling the updates and reloading works! thank you.

Comment: These were already checked for me, but unchecking and rechecking them and then reloading also works.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Ubuntu 14.04 of the source is too old or not accessible.So we should update the source.That will be resolved. First, we should backup the source file `sources.list`

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list_backup
```

According to the Ubuntu's version to add the new sources.

1. Query the version command:

   ```
   lsb_release -a
   ```

   Then it will print the information such as:

   ```
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
   Release:    14.04
   Codename:   trusty
   ```
2. According to the verison to choice suitbale source and add to the end of the '/etc/apt/sources.list' file.

   ```
   http://wiki.ubuntu.org.cn/Template:14.04source，
   ```

   Ubuntu 14.04 source:

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   ```
3. Update source

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. OK

   ```
   sudo apt-get install g++
   ```